# Chrome extension cant read value from div

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

i have a problem reading a value from my div in my chrome extension.
Here is my window.html:

```
<body>
<div class="aussen" align="center">
<div class="box">
<div class="ribbon"><span>beta</span></div>

    </div>
        <div class="innen">
            <div class="results">

            </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <small>2018</small>
     <div id="status"></div>
        </div>
   </div>

</div>
</body>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
  chrome.storage.sync.get('hstid', function(data) {
     document.getElementById("status").innerText = data.hstid;
     console.log("hstid is in fkt: "+"'"+data.hstid+"'");
  });
var x=document.getElementById('status').value;
```

My Problem is that my variable x is null i cant assign x my value.
I got the problem `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`.

Can you help me, how my variable x could also get the value from this div ?

Thanks Paul

Comment: 1. div doesn't have `value` property 2. chrome.* API is asynchronous so you need to use the value inside the callback because it runs *after* the code that follows.

Comment: Thank you. It works. great answer